# Wordpress - How can I access the custom post archive in browser?

Tags: php, wordpress, post, permalinks

This question may sound silly but it's really been giving me headaches. I created a custom post type name services and I also created a file name archive-services.php in the root of my theme folder in which I created a loop so that only the custom posts in services can be displayed. I didn't create any taxonomy since I won't be using them.

My permalinks are as follows: `/%category%/%postname%/` so I'd expect that when accesing www.mydomain.com/services to see the archive page created.

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since services is not a category, I don't think it should be accessible through existing .htaccess. Have you tried adding a rewrite rule to .htaccess so that `/services` will be redirected to your PHP file?

Comment: did you enable the archive when you registered your custom post with has_archive?

Comment: Hello Tom, yes actually I didn't registered my custom post with has_archive, thanks a lot. You saved me a lot of time.